# boost 1.49 for ubuntu and libboost_date_time

Tags: c++, boost

I just installed the boost 1.49 version on ubuntu and the process went smooth. however, now when I am running any of my files(hence I am not posting the c++ file because it is happening with every file that use libboost_date_time), I get the following error:

```
./test.shared.array.exe: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_date_time.so.1.49.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I checked to see where boost.build installed the library and I see the `libboost_date_time.so.1.49.0` in `/usr/local/`

why then would I be getting such error. how can i fix the issue.

these are the contents of the `/usr/local/boost_1_49_0`

```
/usr/local/boost_1_49_0$ ls
b2      boost-build.jam  bootstrap.bat  index.htm   libs                rst.css
bin.v2  boostcpp.jam     bootstrap.log  index.html  LICENSE_1_0.txt     status
bjam    boost.css        bootstrap.sh   INSTALL     more                tools
boost   boost.png        doc            Jamroot     project-config.jam
```

and this is what I have in

```
/usr/local/lib$ ls
libboost_chrono.a              libboost_prg_exec_monitor.so.1.49.0
libboost_chrono.so             libboost_program_options.a
libboost_chrono.so.1.49.0      libboost_program_options.so
libboost_date_time.a           libboost_program_options.so.1.49.0
libboost_date_time.so          libboost_random.a
libboost_date_time.so.1.49.0   libboost_random.so
libboost_exception.a           libboost_random.so.1.49.0
libboost_filesystem.a          libboost_regex.a
libboost_filesystem.so         libboost_regex.so
libboost_filesystem.so.1.49.0  libboost_regex.so.1.49.0
libboost_graph.a               libboost_serialization.a
libboost_graph.so              libboost_serialization.so
libboost_graph.so.1.49.0       libboost_serialization.so.1.49.0
libboost_iostreams.a           libboost_signals.a
libboost_iostreams.so          libboost_signals.so
libboost_iostreams.so.1.49.0   libboost_signals.so.1.49.0
libboost_locale.a              libboost_system.a
libboost_locale.so             libboost_system.so
libboost_locale.so.1.49.0      libboost_system.so.1.49.0
libboost_math_c99.a            libboost_test_exec_monitor.a
libboost_math_c99f.a           libboost_thread.a
libboost_math_c99f.so          libboost_thread.so
libboost_math_c99f.so.1.49.0   libboost_thread.so.1.49.0
libboost_math_c99l.a           libboost_timer.a
libboost_math_c99l.so          libboost_timer.so
libboost_math_c99l.so.1.49.0   libboost_timer.so.1.49.0
libboost_math_c99.so           libboost_unit_test_framework.a
libboost_math_c99.so.1.49.0    libboost_unit_test_framework.so
libboost_math_tr1.a            libboost_unit_test_framework.so.1.49.0
libboost_math_tr1f.a           libboost_wave.a
libboost_math_tr1f.so          libboost_wave.so
libboost_math_tr1f.so.1.49.0   libboost_wave.so.1.49.0
libboost_math_tr1l.a           libboost_wserialization.a
libboost_math_tr1l.so          libboost_wserialization.so
libboost_math_tr1l.so.1.49.0   libboost_wserialization.so.1.49.0
libboost_math_tr1.so           ocaml
libboost_math_tr1.so.1.49.0    perl
libboost_prg_exec_monitor.a    python2.7
libboost_prg_exec_monitor.so   R
```

Comment: Your system probably isn't looking for .so's in this folder.  Check your /etc/ld.so.conf file.  I'm used to the boost libraries installed in /usr/lib ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Your system probably isn't looking for the .so's in this path.**

Check /etc/ld.so.conf to see which directories are searched for so's.
/usr/local is an odd location for those to be installed in.  I'd expect /usr/lib or /usr/local/lib.

[EDIT to reflect new information]

Since you have installed boost in /usr/local/lib (I'm assuming all the .so's are under there) and this path is already in **/etc/ld.so.conf.d** you can try running ldconfig:

> sudo ldconfig

Make sure you are compiling with the right libraries, e.g.:

> gcc test.shared.array.cpp -lboost_date_time

Comment: I have 4 files in that directory (GL.conf, i686-linux-gnu.conf, libasound2.conf, libc.conf) and these are the contents of libc.conf `# libc default configuration
/usr/local/lib`. I checked in `/usr/local/lib` and I do have `libboost_date_time.so.1.49.0` in that directory also, but not in `/usr/lib`. I installed boost in `/usr/local/boost_1_49_0/`. I did have everything working fine with boost_1.42 that I installed from the applications folder but then I was suggested to install the 1.49 version so I have both versions. is there a way i can uninstall 1.49, as I cannot run anything now.

Comment: @user1155299: You might as well use 1.49 since you've installed it and it is the most current version.  You can either put the .so's in a folder that the system searches or add your install folder as I describe above.  Let me know if you have any issues while doing that...

Comment: I just edited my post with the contents of the `/usr/local/boost_1_49_0`. I don't see the .so's directly in that folder, should I still install the folder in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d`

Comment: I have created the file, and I will await your confirmation before I run the ldconfig.

Comment: @user1155299: No.  You need /usr/local/lib as that is where the .so's are.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: @user1155299: But I guess /usr/local/lib should already be in your search path.  just try running ldconfig and see if that resolves the problem.

Comment: @user1155299: How are you compiling your software? Are you doing -lboost_date_time ?

Comment: yes indeed, that is how I am doing it. THANK YOU, Guy, it solved the problem. curious how that could have solved the problem though...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9297/discussion-between-guy-sirton-and-user1155299)